# Prove that a Verma module is projective only if its highest weight is dominant?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ with a fixed Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ and a fixed system of simple roots. It is stated in Exercise 3.11 of Humphreys' book "Representations of semisimple Lie algebras in the BGG category $\mathcal{O}$" that

*The Verma $U(\mathfrak{g})$-module $M(\lambda)$ of highest weight $\lambda$ is projective only if $\lambda$ is dominant.*

Can anyone give me some hint to prove this proposition? It seems related to the BGG reciprocity.

Comment: Hint: If $\lambda$ is not dominant, then there is some $\mu\neq \lambda$ such that $L(\lambda)$ is a composition factor of $M(\mu)$. Now apply BGG reciprocity.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks for the comments. I know that if $L(\mu)$ is a composition factor of $M(\lambda)$, then $\mu\leq \lambda$. But why $M(\lambda)$ has a composition factor $L(\mu)$ with $\mu\neq\lambda$?

Comment: Not $M(\lambda)$ but $M(\mu)$. Think of what submodules are in Verma modules.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Indeed, this is my question. I do not know which $L(\mu)$ does appear as a composition factor of $M(\lambda)$. Is it possible that $M(\lambda)$ is irreducible when $\lambda$ is dominant?

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking of using Proposition 1.4, but you need some integrality for that.

Comment: @Zhihua: Maybe I can prevent some confusion by pointing to the revision list for my book, where this misplaced exercise is rewritten.  It's much easier to prove in the stronger form after section 4.7.   See the current list of revisions at the AMS page http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/gsm-94

Comment: @JimHumphreys Thank you very much! I will continue reading the book.

Comment: @JimHumphreys Ahh, that explains why I could not make my hint into a full solution (I wrote the original hint before I had a closer look at what was presented before the exercise).

Comment: @Tobias: Yes, it's always a problem with placement of exercises.   As usual my excuse is lack of opportunity to work through the material in the book with actual students, so the feedback comes later.